# image saving to a dic and display them with php

Tags: php, html, image

```
<body>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["submit_photo"])) 
{
    processform();
} else {
    displayform();
}

function processform() 
{
    if (isset($_FILES["photo"]) and $_FILES["photo"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
    {
        if ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] != "image/png") 
        {
            echo " png image please, thank you";

        }
        else if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["temp_name"], "photos/".basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]))) 
        {
        echo "sorry there was a problem uploading photots".$_FILES["photo"]["error"];

    } else {
        displaythanks();
    }

} else {
    switch ($_FILES["photo"]["error"]) 
    {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: 
            $message =  "The photo is larger than the server allows";
            break;

        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            $message = "The photo is larger than the script allows";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            $message= "No file selected to be uploaded";
            break;

        default:
            $message= "please contact your administrator for help";
            break;
        }
        echo "Sorry there was a problem with uploading photos. ".$message;  
    }
}

function displayform()
{?>
    <h1> Uploading a photo </h1>
    <form style="width:30em" action="photo_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">               
    <label for="visitor_name">Your Name :</label>
    <input type="text" name="visitor_name" id="visitor_name" value="" /><br />
    <label for="photo">Your Photo:</label>
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" value="" /><br />                
    <input type="submit" name="submit_photo" id="submit_photo" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<?php       
}
function displaythanks() 
{
    echo "thanks for uploading your photo ". $_POST["visitor_name"];
    echo "here is your photo";
?>
    <p><img scr="photos/<?php echo $_FILES["photo"]["name"] ?>" alt="photo"/></p>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
```

i have been trying to get an png image using that form and save it to the photo folder which is located in the same directory(root folder) and display it . whats happening is when i hit the submit button it doesn't save it to that photos/ folder neither it displays. i have been browsing everywhere to find a solution but most of them wrote almost same way i did. but some reason its not working . Am i doing something wrong? if so can you point out please. and also i would like any solution for this. thanks guys.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, plus make sure the folder has proper permissions to write to it.

Comment: Btw, the syntax is `["tmp_name"]` and not `["temp_name"]` - whoever wants to bite on this to put in an answer, go right ahead. Questions as such as off-topic on Stack which is why I am not putting one in.

Comment: I hope you actually indent your code because those nested if statements are a nightmare to read

Comment: im so stupid . After adding your code when I run the programme on the dserver I got another error which pointed out as undiffiend index where I write temp_name it suppose to be tmp_name . Fixed that issue and successfully saved image to that photos folder but now it's not displaying the image .. Any solution?

Comment: Noob.. Php have both '&&'  and 'and'  operator. 'And' operator has lower precedence than '&&' operator but both work almost same way ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code got two problems, but before explaining them please give a nice style to your code so it'll be readable

Problem 1. You misspelled `$_FILES["photo"]["temp_name"]`
, it should be `$_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]`

Problem 2. In php when you are trying to upload a file first it'll upload the file into a template folder, then let's programmer decide to upload it or not which is your rules for example max upload size, format ... at the end if you decide to upload files you have to use move_uploaded_file() function, but in your code this line is in the `else if` part so if the image type is png  your code will never reach that line. here is the corrected code :

```
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit_photo"]))
{
    processform();
}
else
{
    displayform();
}

function processform()
{
    if (isset($_FILES["photo"]) and $_FILES["photo"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
    {
        if ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] != "image/png")
        {
            echo " png image please, thank you";
        }
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "photos/" .  basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"])))
        {
            echo "sorry there was a problem uploading photots".$_FILES["photo"]["error"];
        }
        else
        {
            displaythanks();

        }

    }
    else
    {
        switch ($_FILES["photo"]["error"])
        {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                $message =  "The photo is larger than the server allows";
                break;

            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                $message = "The photo is larger than the script allows";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                $message= "No file selected to be uploaded";
                break;

            default:
                $message= "please contact your administrator for help";
                break;
        }
        echo "Sorry there was a problem with uploading photos. ".$message;
    }
}

function displayform()
{?>
    <h1> Uploading a photo </h1>
    <form style="width:30em" action="photo_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="visitor_name">Your Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name="visitor_name" id="visitor_name" value="" /><br />
        <label for="photo">Your Photo:</label>
        <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" value="" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit_photo" id="submit_photo" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<?php
}
function displaythanks()
{
    echo "thanks for uploading your photo ". $_POST["visitor_name"];
    echo "here is your photo";
    ?>
    <p><img scr="photos/<?php echo $_FILES["photo"]["name"] ?>" alt="photo"/></p>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
```

Comment: As I'm new to this site I don't know how to do that

Comment: @Ashifurrahman Click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows.(under "1 Answer" )